# Массивы меняются полностью при добавлении элементов

Tags: массивы, ruby

Есть такая ситуация, в которой я не могу разобраться.
Как пример приведу такой код введенный в irb:

```
array = []          #=> []
array.push("str1")  #=> ["str1"]
array.push("str_2") #=> ["str1", "str_2"]
```

Вроде все понятно и правильно, но, когда я использую тот же код в другом IDE с более старой версией Ruby (irb Ruby v2.4.5, "Другой IDE" Ruby 1.9.2), то я получаю такую картину:

```
array = []          #=> []
array.push("str1")  #=> ["str1"]
array.push("str_2") #=> ["str_2", "str_2"]
```

Кто может объяснить как исправить такое?

Comment: Не может быть. Попробуй 1.9 еще раз.

Comment: Я пробовал и год назад и пол года назад.